# Protobuf.net: OutOfMemoryException

Tags: protobuf-net

I'm getting a System.OutOfMemoryException when calling Serializer.Deserialize on a FileStream.  This happens only on one specific file, and not any other files.  Any ideas why that would be?  All the files are of similar sizes, and all contain similar data, serialized using the same method.

Code (sorry for the VB code - it wasn't my choice)

`Dim loadObj As Object = Nothing
        Using tempStream As FileStream = File.OpenRead(dataFilename)
            loadObj = Serializer.Deserialize(Of MeterReadingsByMeterId)(tempStream)    'fails on 724 every time
            If Not loadObj.GetType() Is GetType(MeterReadingsByMeterId) Then
                loadObj = Nothing
            End If
        End Using`

Stack Trace:

`` Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Resize()
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>>.Add(KeyValuePair`2 keyValuePair)
   at proto_6(Object , ProtoReader )
   at ProtoBuf.Serializers.CompiledSerializer.ProtoBuf.Serializers.IProtoSerializer.Read(Object value, ProtoReader source)
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.Deserialize(Int32 key, Object value, ProtoReader source)
   at ProtoBuf.ProtoReader.ReadTypedObject(Object value, Int32 key, ProtoReader reader, Type type)
   at ProtoBuf.ProtoReader.ReadObject(Object value, Int32 key, ProtoReader reader)
   at proto_4(Object , ProtoReader )
   at ProtoBuf.Serializers.CompiledSerializer.ProtoBuf.Serializers.IProtoSerializer.Read(Object value, ProtoReader source)
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.Deserialize(Int32 key, Object value, ProtoReader source)
   at ProtoBuf.ProtoReader.ReadTypedObject(Object value, Int32 key, ProtoReader reader, Type type)
   at ProtoBuf.ProtoReader.ReadObject(Object value, Int32 key, ProtoReader reader)
   at proto_2(Object , ProtoReader )
   at ProtoBuf.Serializers.CompiledSerializer.ProtoBuf.Serializers.IProtoSerializer.Read(Object value, ProtoReader source)
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.Deserialize(Int32 key, Object value, ProtoReader source)
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.DeserializeCore(ProtoReader reader, Type type, Object value, Boolean noAutoCreate)
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.Deserialize(Stream source, Object value, Type type, SerializationContext context)
   at ProtoBuf.Serializer.Deserialize[T](Stream source) ``

Comment: Forgot to mention that I am using r668.

Comment: This could be hard to diagnose without that one specific file; however it looks like it is simply doing dictionary.add, which seems perfectly reasonable. I wonder: how big is the file? Is there any chance you are simply filling x86 memory? (Perhaps created in x64)

Comment: Thanks. I know I'm loading multiple files, so I'll have to check the combined sizes.  If that does end up being the case, could compiling for x64 solve the problem?  Are the size of all data types the same between x86 and x64, or would I have to recreate my data files?

Comment: That was it.  Thanks Marc, you saved me a tonne of panic.  I'm now committing changes more often and it's flowing smoothly again.